# Como obtener los últimos 12 meses ordenado del mas viejo al actual

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en Postgresql

```
Closed   Cancelado   Fecha
45       3           01-01-2019
43       5           01-02-2019
58       8           01-03-2019
61       12          01-04-2019
55       17          01-05-2019
47       7           01-06-2019
65       2           01-07-2019
59       0           01-08-2019
62       1           01-09-2019
40       7           01-10-2019
51       9           01-11-2019
61       4           01-12-2019
60       3           01-01-2020
69       12          01-02-2020
40       11          01-03-2020
46       16          01-04-2020
53       0           01-05-2020
```

Y necesito obtener los ultimos 12 meses y que se visualicen de la siguiente forma

```
Closed   Cancelado   Fecha
47       7           01-06-2019
65       2           01-07-2019
59       0           01-08-2019
62       1           01-09-2019
40       7           01-10-2019
51       9           01-11-2019
61       4           01-12-2019
60       3           01-01-2020
69       12          01-02-2020
40       11          01-03-2020
46       16          01-04-2020
53       0           01-05-2020
```

la Query que arme es la siguiente pero me lo orden al revés de como lo necesito

```
SELECT Closed, Cancelados, fecha FROM tabla order by fecha desc limit 12;

53       0           01-05-2020
46       16          01-04-2020
40       11          01-03-2020
69       12          01-02-2020
60       3           01-01-2020
61       4           01-12-2019
51       9           01-11-2019
40       7           01-10-2019
62       1           01-09-2019
59       0           01-08-2019
65       2           01-07-2019
47       7           01-06-2019
```

Cabe aclarar que si cambio el DESC por ASC no me trae los ultimos 12 si no que los primero 12 de la tabla, y por desgracia no encontre como ordenar 2 veces el mismo campo.

tambien intente usar la funcion`WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND now()`

pero no me funciona en postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de lograr lo que quieres hacer es realizando una subconsulta:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 12) as aliasSub ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```